# Iteration over two list in Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, list, loops, iteration

I'm trying to iterate over two list - I'm working on a tool which will fill a web form, I already have some nice selenium code but I have a problem with the loop which will get email and ID from excel file. So I got an error:

```
for DUNS_data, Email_data in EmailsAdressCore():
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I already tried to use `ddof=1` but I don't know where should I add this...

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

EmailsAdressCore = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\M0099969\Desktop\VW\DUNSBase.xlsx', sheet_name='Arkusz1')

DUNS_data = EmailsAdressCore['DUNS'].values.tolist()
Email_data = EmailsAdressCore['email'].values.tolist()

for DUNS_data, Email_data in EmailsAdressCore():
    print('DUNS: ' + DUNS_data + 'Email adress is:' + Email_data)
```

So I would like to be able to print these two columns next to each other, I need this code to fill the form over the loop.

Comment: Sorry I forgot how to type code here, so I removed it and I got:  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: While you can create two lists from two columns and then `zip` them, I find it more logical to iterate over the rows of the Dataframe using the `iterrows` method and then extract the two values you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way to iterate over 2 and more list is:

```
import itertools
from itertools import zip_longest   

CategoryCore = pd.read_excel, sheet_name='Arkusz1')
IssueDesc = CategoryCore['Issue:'].values.tolist()
Category = CategoryCore['Category'].values.tolist()

for (a,b)  in itertools.zip_longest(IssueDesc, Category):
print(a,b)
```

I couldn't find any other way and this loop works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

`EmailsAdressCore` is not a function, so you cannot try to call it using `()`. And you already extracted `DUNS_data` and `Email_data`, so you should just iterate over that.

I think what you are looking for is:

```
for d1, d2 in zip(DUNS_data, Email_data):
    print('DUNS: ' + d1 + 'Email adress is:' + d2)
```